# As an Artillerist Artificer, can I use my eldritch cannons while under an entanglement spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, artificer

In *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, the Artillerist subclass for the artificer gets a feature called Eldritch Cannon that you summon as a small or tiny object. If my character is under the effects of the *entangle* spell and my cannon is separate from me, can I still fire it?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the spell [*entangle*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

#### You can still fire your cannons, but you have disadvantage on attack rolls.

[*Entangle*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle) states:

> A creature in the area when you cast the spell must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be **restrained** by the entangling plants until the spell ends.

The [Restrained condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained) says:

> Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.

So if you are using the Force Ballista Cannon while under the effect of *entangle*, you have disadvantage on the attack roll, since the [Force Ballista description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#EldritchCannonsTable) says:

> Make a ranged spell attack

Fortunately, nothing in the description of *entangle* or the Restrained condition prevents you from using your cannon, and the Flamethrower and Protector cannons would be totally unimpeded, as neither of those use attack rolls (Flamethrower forces a saving throw and Protector just works).

#### The condition you have to watch out for is Incapacitated.

Here's a bit of bonus content that will be good to know moving forward as an Artillerist. The conditions that will prevent you from using your cannons are:

- [Incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated)
- [Paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed)
- [Stunned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Stunned)

Paralyzed and Stunned also make you Incapacitated, and the rules for the Incapacitated condition state:

> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

But using my cannons is a bonus action, what gives? The [rules for bonus actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) state:

> anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action.

For example, if you were under the effects of [*hold person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hold-person), which inflicts Paralyzed, you would not be able to use your bonus action to activate your cannon.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you can.

The relevant rules text for [Entangle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle) is

> A creature in the area when you cast the spell must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be restrained by the entangling plants until the spell ends.

If you are under the spell's effect, you suffer the *restrained condition*:

> A restrained creature’s speed becomes 0, and it can’t benefit from any bonus to its speed. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature’s Attack rolls have disadvantage. The creature has disadvantage on Dexterity Saving Throws.

The relevant rules text for **Eldritch Cannon** is:

> **ELDRITCH CANNON** (...) you can take an action to magically create a Small or Tiny eldritch cannon in an unoccupied space on a horizontal surface within 5 feet of you. (...) The cannon is a magical object. (...) On each of your turns, you can take a bonus action to cause the cannon to activate if you are within 60 feet of it.

Entangle creates *difficult terrain*, but does not make the area count occupied. The cannon will be within 60 feet of you, and nothing about being restrained stops you from firing it.

If you chose a form of cannon that requires an attack roll, like the **Force Ballista**, you will make that **attack with disadvantage**, since you are the one making the attack roll and you are restrained.

> **Force Ballista**: Make a ranged spell attack, originating
> from the cannon, at one creature or object within 120 feet ofit.

If you chose a form of the cannon that does not make attack rolls, like the **Flamethrower**, you will not suffer a negative effect in firing it from being restrained:

> **Flamethrower**: The cannon exhales fire in an adjacent 15-
> foot cone that you designate. Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving throw against your spell save DC,

Also, the Cannon is an **Object**, not a **Creature**. Therefore, if you create it with legs, it will technically not be subject to the effect of *Entangle* (which affects only creatures) for the purpose of walking somewhere else (I as GM would overrule such technical arguments).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134001/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-groody-the-hobgoblin).